# how to fix AttributeError

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm making a web wrapper with python.

but i can't fix the error   **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'**

this is my code

```
def extract_indeed_jobs(last_page):
    jobs = []
    # for page in range(last_page):
    result = requests.get(f"{URL}&start={0*LIMIT}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "jobsearch-SerpJobCard"})
    # print(results)       It works!!

    for result in results:
        # print(results)      It works!!
        title = result.find("h2", {"class:": "title"})
        # i think above line is the problem but i dont konw how to fix it
        # 'results' have <h2> tag, i checked from printed out 'results'
        print(title.find("a"))

    return jobs
```

i think ***title = result.find("h2", {"class:": "title"})*** is the problem
but don't know how to fix it

this code didn't help me

```
title = result.find("a", {"class":"jobtitle"})["title"]
```

I appreciate any hint :)

all code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LIMIT = 50

URL = f"https://kr.indeed.com/취업?q=python&limit={LIMIT}"


def extract_indeed_pages():
    result = requests.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

    pagination = soup.find("div", {"class": "pagination"})

    links = pagination.find_all('a')
    pages = []

    for link in links[:-1]:
        pages.append(int(link.string))

    max_page = pages[-1]
    return max_page


def extract_indeed_jobs(last_page):
    jobs = []
    # for page in range(last_page):
    result = requests.get(f"{URL}&start={0*LIMIT}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "jobsearch-SerpJobCard"})

    for result in results:
        if not result:
            results.remove(result)

    for result in results:
        title = result.find("h2", {"class:": "title"})
        print(title.find("a"))

    return jobs
```

Comment: I don't think the error can be coming from that line. It's probably `title.find("a")`. Show the full traceback.

Comment: @BekhruzNiyazov I don't think there's any way that `find_all()` can return a list that includes `None`.

Comment: @Barmar well, if you think about it logically there should be. If the user does not get the error in `for result in results` that means that `result` is a list. If `results` were equal to `[ ]` there would not be any errors. But if you look at an error message, you'll see that `"NoneType object has no attribute find"` and that means that `result` is equal to `None` and that means that there is a `None` in `results` list.

Comment: @BekhruzNiyazov There are two calls to `find()`. Since `find_all()` is guaranteed to return a list of objects, `result` can't be `None`. By process of elimination the error must be in the other call, `title.find("a")`, so `title` is `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

You try to `find()` the title that way, but you will never get a match, cause of the attribute `class:`:

```
title = result.find("h2", {"class:": "title"})
```

### How to fix that?

Just delete the typo `:` in your "class:" definition:

```
title = result.find("h2", {"class": "title"})
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Vollzeit&l=Bremen&start=40").text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "jobsearch-SerpJobCard"})

for result in results:
    title = result.find("h2", {"class": "title"})
    print(title.a.text)
```

**Output**

```
Mediengestalter (Bild&Ton)/ Filmemacher in Teil-/Vollzeit

Freelance (m/w/d)

Immobilienmakler (m/w/x) mit Festgehalt und ungedeckelter Pr...

Fahrer (m/w/d) für Betonmischer in Bremen

Glasreiniger / Gehilfe Vollzeit

Helfer Verpackung (m/w/d)

Ehrenamtliche Helfer (m/w/d)
```